# Log = new Log("debug");

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do I fix this?

```
var Log = require("log"),
  log = new Log("debug");


server.listen(port, function() {
  log.info("Listening port %s", port);
});
```

log.info("Listening port %s", port);

TypeError: log.info is not a function

Comment: Replace `var Log = require("log"),  log = new Log("debug");` with `var log = require("log");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var log = require("log"),

server.listen(port, function() {
  log.debug("Listening port %s", port);
});
```

Try it like this